# Payment Express Hosted Payment always gived declined respond for testing

Tags: payment-gateway, payment, credit-card

I tried to make online payment for malaysian site use using Payment Express.
I register developer account in payment express site then set up everything to work in testing purpose .

my problem is why it always return 'DECLINED' respond whatever credit card I use.
I tried using this card numbers :

> VISA: 4111111111111111
>
> MasterCard: 5431111111111111
>
> American Express: 371111111111114
>
> Diners Club: 36000000000008

here is their respond as always :

> ** Authorization Result**
>
> Response:     DECLINED
>
> Response Code:    JA
>
> Currency: MYR
>
> Amount:   200.00
>
> Card:     543111........11
>
> Card Holder:  bnmb josep
>
> Type:
>
> Date:     20150227
>
> Time:     113543
>
> Transaction Type:     Purchase
>
> Help Text:    The transaction was Declined (JA)

I already read their documentation but no answer and I also send email to them but still no respond yet, I hope somebody in stackoverflow can help me.
Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

i got ReCo JA (BillingID not Matched), I think I got mis understanding with tokenize. to solve this problem just remove BillingID from request.